# I am having trouble creating a database in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, html, phpmyadmin, xampp

Hi I'm trying to create a database but when i am creating a db, this happens.

[image: Screen-shot]

I tried re-installing and importing a database but still no luck.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If you are using a hosting service, have you tried doing it through CPanel or any other host management service that your server might user?

Comment: have you tried doing from cmd line? see if it's mysql err or phpmyadmin

Comment: I am currently using this for a school assignment so it is required that we use xampp and phpmyadmin.

Comment: You should try using a db manager like SQLyog

Comment: @DeanCiantar harsh - real world development usually means using neither tool xD

Comment: I would try it without the dot in the database name (in "4.2D")